# Trying to generate Chart Line on google sheet but with info horizontaly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have the following info in google sheet, but all documentation to create google chart is more about to read the info in a vertical way and i have code to read it vertical but as you see my info is horizontal...

[image]

My code only read vertical, how can i adapt it to my google sheet information?

```
function generarGraficoHorizontal() {
  var hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var rango = hoja.getRange('A1:D10'); 
  var grafico = hoja.newChart()
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
    .addRange(rango)
    .setPosition(2, 5, 0, 0)
    .build();

  hoja.insertChart(grafico);
}
```

Comment: `Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data.` Thank you for supplying the screen shot of your data; that is helpful. But it requires that users must create their own data to test your code and/or solution. Please consider supplying the data in the body of your question as a markdown table. Would you also include an example of the chart based on a successful outcome.

Comment: Please add a minimum reproducible sample of your current project. Please also include your expected output on this one. This way the community will have a better overview of your objectives with your question. I do apologize but after trying to test your code with random numbers I cannot make sense of the attributes Horizontal and Vertical. You might want to look at your range as source of your data. It doesn't make sense with your current data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have data that is laid out "vertically" but your chart script assumes horizontal format.

The "answer" is that you need to transpose your data. This can be done physically (there are plenty of examples on StackOverflow) OR you can do it within the ChartBuilder with the method:

`.setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)`

Obviously the "virtual, ChartBuilder approach offers the ability to create the chart without copy/pasting your data.

Also use `.setNumHeaders(1)` to create the the x-axis labels

---

```
function generarGraficoHorizontal() {
  var hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var rango = hoja.getRange('A1:D10'); 
  var grafico = hoja.newChart()
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
    .addRange(rango)
    .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
    .setPosition(2, 5, 0, 0)
    .build();

  hoja.insertChart(grafico);
}
```

---

[setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-line-chart-builder#settransposerowsandcolumnstranspose)

[.setNumHeaders(1)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-line-chart-builder#setnumheadersheaders)

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: snapshot]

---

Comment: This seems to work, but i cant see all the months in the X axis, as in your example i only see a few months, no all of them

Comment: `as in your example i only see a few months, no all of them` I deliberately chose the same data range as you => `var rango = hoja.getRange('A1:D10');`  Transpose this, and you get three months of data. So, just expand your range to select as much data as you wish.